# Estimating effect of latent variable in regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I believe that independent variables $X_1,X_2$ affect the dependent variable $Y$ through a latent variable $Z$ such that 
$$
\begin{align}
Y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1Z \\
Z &= \operatorname{Logit}^{-1}(\beta_2X_1 + \beta_3X_2) \\
\\
Y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1\operatorname{Logit}^{-1}(\beta_2X_1 + \beta_3X_2)
\end{align}
$$

Is it possible to estimate $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$, given $Y$?

Comment: `Expit`="Inverse logit function" from the [msm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/index.html) package?

Comment: yes, I'll fix the question so that it's clear I'm talking about the inverse logit fuction.

Comment: if $X_1$ and and $X_2$ are given the obvious choice is non-linear least squares. What are the conditions on model errors? Depending on them better estimating technique can be used.

Comment: note that with the current equations $Z$ is **not** binary variable.

Comment: excellent point, I am interpreting Z as an expectation that Z will take on one of two values, but Z is continuous from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One answer is "no."  Another is, "of course."

#### No

To simplify notation, let $\lambda(x) = 1/(1 + \exp(-x))$, the inverse logit.  Because $\lambda(x) = 1 - \lambda(-x)$,

$$\beta_0 + \beta_1 \lambda(x) = (\beta_0 + \beta_1) - \beta_1 \lambda(-x)).$$

Therefore it is impossible to distinguish the parameters $(\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)$ from $(\beta_0+\beta_1, -\beta_1, -\beta_2, -\beta_3)$.

#### Of course

Let us stipulate that the first nonzero element of $(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)$ must be positive.  That resolves the indeterminacy.  We still need a model for the errors.  If we suppose, for instance, that $Y - \left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \lambda(\beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3)\right)$ has a Normal distribution and the various $Y$'s are independent, then we can use least squares to estimate the parameters.  There is no exact solution to this nonlinear optimization problem, but it is straightforward to do numerically.

[image: 50 data points and their fit as a surface]

This graphic shows 50 points generated with standard Normal values for $X_1$ and $X_2$, parameter $\beta = (1,2,1/2,-1)$, with iid Normal errors of standard deviation 1/2.  The surface shows the fit, $\hat{\beta} = (2.68, -1.23, -0.89, 1.75) \sim (1.45, 1.23, 0.89, -1.75)$.

Least squares is the maximum likelihood with iid Normal errors.  With another error distribution, use MLE directly.  You can obtain asymptotic confidence intervals for the parameters in the standard ways.